# array[0] = 0 how is this possible?

Tags: c++, arrays

an array can't be defined as c[0], it at least has to be like c[1]
Why is the following code correct? What is he doing there?
Thank you for the explanation.

**edit: sorry guys, I'm writing C++ code in VS2012**

```
int foo(double c[], int n) 
{

    if (n==1) {
        c[0] = 0;      //why is this possible?
    } else {
.
.
.

}
```

Comment: Because arrayIndex starts from 0. Also, which language you are talking about ??!!

Comment: Pick up a C book.

Comment: I can't see reason for the downvotes. As a beginner's question this is completely legal and well formulated. Given the fact that most, even experienced, C/C++ programmers often make out of bound array index access errors, this question isn't too bad or trivial at all (run a serious static code analysis tool over your code, and you'll get my point).

Answer (score 6):

`double c[]`, in argument position, is syntactic sugar for `double *c`; it's actually a pointer. Similarly, `c[0]` is sugar for `*c`.

`c[0] = 0;` is not an array declaration. It's an assignment to the first element of the array pointed to by `c`.

Comment: Thank you! I am just a beginner. You are saying that *c is a pointer of the array c? Please could you explain a little more? I'm not really familiar with the terminology sugar :)

Comment: @lulumink: no, I'm saying `c` is a pointer disguising as an array.

Comment: in c++, we cannot declare an array like double array[], but you can do that in the argument of a function? I got that c[0] = 0 means that I assign 0 to the first element of that c array. but why can we declare the array like this array[]?

Comment: You probably want to roll back that edit -- for better or worse, @chico is just plain wrong on this. (N3337, §8.3.5/5): "...any parameter of type “array of T” [...] is adjusted to be “pointer to T”" (note, *not* "constant pointer to T").

Comment: @JerryCoffin: in C or in C++, or both? We originally assumed the OP was writing C.

Comment: @larsmans The `const` shouldn't be there. When used as a parameter declaration, `double c[]` is converted into `double* c` by the compiler.

Comment: @chico There is no array variable in any of the code shown.  (Hopefully, there is one at the call site.)

Comment: @larsmans While you're at it: `c[0]` is actually `*(c + 0)` (which is `*c`); more generally, `c[i]` is `*(c + i)`.

Comment: @larsmans: Same idea: (C99, §6.7.5.3/7): "A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation."

Comment: @JamesKanze, tks, sorry for the confusion whatsoever, I didn't expected this for the array parameter, I've checked setting the variable and indeed, it can be set.

Comment: Well I see no point in array parameters like this anymore, not even the constness context from true arrays is preserved. The only advantage that lasts for me, is the indication it can provide that the argument will be used as an array of values by the function, and not that it's just a pointer to a single value.

Answer (score 2):

In a variable declaration `c[0]` means "c is an array of size 0". Since arrays of size 0 don't exist (and wouldn't make sense) in C or C++, that is, as you point out, illegal.

As an expression `c[0]` means "get the element at index 0 of c". Since C arrays are 0-indexed valid indices for an array of size n are 0 through n-1. Since the size of an array always has to be greater than 0, 0 is always a valid index for any array. So it's always legal to write `c[0]` if `c` is an array or a pointer to valid memory.

And since `c[i]` is an expression that produces an lvalue, it is also always legal to write `c[0] = someValue` (unless `c` is `const`).

Comment: Thank you sepp2k for the detailed explanation. I'm actually using c++. So that means you can't declare c[0], but you can access the first element of an array by using c[0]?

Comment: @lulumink It's the same for C++. And yes, you can't declare arrays of size 0, but you can, of course, access the first element of an array (which you do by writing `c[0]`).

Comment: Danke schön Sepp :) Super klare Erklärung.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, the array name c can be thought as a synonym for the address of the first element in the array.
suppose we have array double c[] as,
[image]

we already know that array index always start from 0

using c[0] notation, we can access the first element that is 21

but actually compiler convert c[0] to *(c+0) to access the first element.

similarly, we can directly use these pointer notation in our program.

For example, to access the third element which could be accessed using index c[2],
we can use pointer  *(c+2).

```
Thus , 
             in array ,  c[0] means *(c+0) 
                         c[1] means *(c+1) 
                         c[2] means *(c+2) and so on.
```

Comment: An array name is not a *synonym* for the address of the first element. An expression of array type is *converted* (in most but not all contexts) to a pointer to the array's first element. For example, given `int arr[100];`, the expression `sizeof arr` gives you the size of the array object, *not* the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

"an array can't be defined as c[0]"

It can be!

The **array member with 0 number** is **the first member of the array**.

The **array member with 1 number** is **the second member of the array**.

Overall:

The **array member with X number** is **the X+1th member of the array**.

It's not sorcery: the reason is that the computer doesn't count as we count, the decimal numeral system starts with number zero.

Comment: I think this misses the point that the OP confused a *declaration* of `c[0]` with an *expresssion* `c[0]`.

Comment: Thanks. I maybe didn't say it clearly. What I meant was we cannot declare an array like int c[0]; in c++. the compiler wouldn't allow it. But thanks anyway!!!

Comment: Oh...because of the "**...**" I thought that you didn't show the declaration.  In that case, I also don't know, how is this possible, but I don't even mind. Why I would create an array with less than 2 elements?! Of course, the question is totally right and good, but this is not an important problem _for me._